# Installing GEOS on heroku cedar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, geos, rgeo

we have troubles in installing the GEOS library on heroku cedar stack.

We followed this guide: https://devcenter.spacialdb.com/Heroku.html and it didn't work.

We noticed that the path (/app/tmp/geos) stored in the provided geos binaries was wrong, so we built our own binaries with vulcan.

We changed parameters (BUNDLE_BUILD__RGEO) accordingly, but we weren't able to make it work.

We even hardcoded geos paths in our custom rgeo gem without any success

We also tried other buildscripts (https://github.com/roximity/heroku-buildpack-ruby-geos) but they are too old and it will be difficult to keep them up to date with heroku's one

We are using ruby 2.0.0-p195 and Rails 3.2.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created [heroku-buildpack-rgeo-prep](https://github.com/aaronrenner/heroku-buildpack-rgeo-prep) to address this problem.

This buildpack overwrites .bundle/config to set BUNDLE_BUILD__RGEO to the current build path. Unfortunately, you can't set BUNDLE_BUILD_RGEO=/app because your project is actually built somewhere like /tmp/build_1890cktlpat5d.

Hopefully, this buildpack will make it much less painful to use RGeo on Heroku.

Comment: Did you set BUILDPACK_URL to https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git? You will also create a .buildpacks file, to tell heroku-buildpack-multi which other buildpacks to run. Feel free to post an issue to the repo if this doesn't help and I can try to help there.

Comment: actually there were some problems with heroku last night, so forget about my last comment. thanks again for your quick response

Answer (score 2):

One of the current maintainer of the [RGeo gem](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo). We're improving documentation, and I've edited [the part mentioning geos installation on heroku](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/blob/main/doc/Enable-GEOS-and-Proj4-on-Heroku.md).

To avoid any link rot, here's a solution that should work:

```bash
echo 'libgeos-dev=3.7.1-1~pgdg18.04+1' > Aptfile # Use the version you want here
git add Aptfile
git commit -m 'Add Aptfile with libgeos'
heroku buildpacks:add --index=1 heroku-community/apt
# If you already have installed the gem earlier, you will need to purge your repo cache:
#   heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
#   heroku repo:purge_cache
git push heroku main
heroku console <<< 'puts "RGeo is configured with Geos !" if RGeo::Geos.capi_supported?;exit'
```

And if you also want support from the standard geographic libraries (such as Proj4), you should consider using the [heroku-geo-buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack). This will be a bit slower and you'll have a bigger slug since it will install libraries you may not need.