# Installing GEOS on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, geos, rgeo

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app (*ruby 2.3.0, rails 4.2.6*) to Heroku that uses the [RGeo](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo) gem, but I'm having no luck installing the underlying GEOS library upon which the RGeo gem relies (See https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo#dependencies).

According to [Heroku's own instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgis#setting-up-postgis-with-rails), this should be possible by using the [heroku-geo-buildpack](https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack), but it's not working.

**ADD BUILDPACK TO APP:**

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby
```

**BUILD PROCESS LOOKS GOOD:**

```
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> geos/gdal/proj app detected
remote:        Using geos version: 3.4.2
remote:        Using gdal version: 1.11.1
remote:        Using proj version: 4.8.0_1
remote: -----> Vendoring geo libraries done
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.0
```

**TEST DEPENDENCY:**

```
>>> require 'rgeo'
=> false
>>> RGeo::CoordSys::Proj4.supported?
=> true
>>> RGeo::Geos.supported?
=> false
```

Comment: Did you run the buildpack before adding the buildpack for the languages as the documentation says ? After adding the buildpack it says you should build it using "heroku buildpacks".

Comment: @AlexanderLuna yes I detailed my process above

Comment: try this link, to install GEOS in heroku : [Install GEOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893840/installing-geos-on-heroku-cedar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the [previously accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41228040/165673) worked at the time, those buildpacks have since been [deprecated](https://github.com/diowa/heroku-buildpack-rgeo-prep#deprecated).

The current solution seems to be to use the newer **[heroku-geo-buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack)**.

Other options can be found here: [rgeoEnable-GEOS-and-Proj4-on-Heroku.md at main · rgeorgeo - GitHub](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/blob/main/doc/Enable-GEOS-and-Proj4-on-Heroku.md)

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be problems getting that specific geos buildpack on heroku, mainly because of the build arguments for geos. For full details you can check [this pull request](https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack/pull/34) to the buildpack where a lot of this is discussed. The solution using a [fork of the webpack](https://github.com/diowa/heroku-buildpack-rgeo-prep) is described in detail in [this blog post](https://www.diowa.com/blog/heroku/2016/02/26/using-rgeo-with-geos-on-heroku).

**STEP 1: Create this `.vendor_urls` file in the root of your project:**

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/diowa-buildpacks/geos-3.5.0-heroku.tar.gz
https://s3.amazonaws.com/diowa-buildpacks/proj-4.9.1-heroku.tar.gz
```

Add this file to git and make sure it ends with a newline.

**STEP 2: Set up your Heroku configuration:**

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/diowa/heroku-buildpack-rgeo-prep.git
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/peterkeen/heroku-buildpack-vendorbinaries.git
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby
heroku config:set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/lib
```

*(SEE https://github.com/diowa/heroku-buildpack-rgeo-prep#setup)*

Finally, note that if you have already installed rgeo, you need to recompile the gem. You can do that by using the [heroku repo plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo), running `heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname` and deploying again.

*(SEE http://www.diowa.com/blog/heroku/2016/02/26/using-rgeo-with-geos-on-heroku#deploy)*

Comment: YES- thanks so much @mlabarca, that solution worked!